# Set an unique field value before a Eloquent model will be created

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a model for my orders table called `Order`. This table has a unique index (a serial number) which is an alphanumerical word. If the user doesn’t set manually, my server has to assign it automatically using the current full year numbers, a set of two fixed letters and an number based on the count of previous `Orders` made on that year (ie `2020XE0054`).

Right now, I’m doing this using a procedure in my MySQL server but I want to do this using just a Laravel 7.3 method or something. My only concern is that two users try to create an order an the server tries to set the same serial number to both.

Comment: do this when u create a model, I dont know your code but it must be like `$model = new Model; $model->field = $request->input(..) ?? now(); $model->save;`

Comment: No because the mode the name of an order is not just numbers. My order name has the year, the letters XE and a correlative number based on how many previous order have been created